# PHP max_execution_time Shows Wrong Value

Tags: php, execution-time

I'm using the following to display the `max_execution_time` of the servers `PHP` settings:

```
echo 'max_execution_time = ' . ini_get('max_execution_time') . '';
```

It returns the value as 0.

However, when I check `phpinfo()` it shows the value is `30`.

Can anyone suggest why `ini_get` isn't returning the correct value? All other settings return the correct value.

Using `php 5.3.28`.

Many thanks.

Comment: Make sure it is not override to `0` for that specific project by setting it in `config` or `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Also make sure there is no ini_set for max_execution_time before that.

Answer (score 1):

The `ini_get()` function returns the value stored in the `php.ini` of a certain parameter.

The `phpinfo()` returns the current used values of all available parameters.

The `max_execution_time` parameter probably does not appear in your `php.ini` file, and thus the response of the `ini_get()` function will be `0`, however this parameter is mandatory for php and have a default value of 30 seconds if not defined in the `php.ini`

for more information read:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php